# What should I tell the recruiter when I am leaving a company with an interesting project but poor management?

Tags: interviewing, job-change, startup, resignation

I have been working full-time for a software startup since I graduated (June 2015). The company is working on a very interesting project, but with very poor management(small team), no vision and no room for career growth which explains the very high turnover rate every year. I first joined because the project was interesting, but now I am convinced that I can't advance in my career in such an environment and that I am working on something that is probably going to fail because of the way it is managed. This even made me depressed most of the time and hate my current job. And trust me, we tried to talk to the manager to do something about it, but in vain.

Right now, I am looking for another job and doing some interviews. And every time I tell the technical recruiter about the project that I am working on, I am asked why do I want to leave because the project is interesting. I know I can say that I am looking for new challenges, which is true, but isn't that the standard answer that every recruiter is expecting to hear? Can I bring that up by any way during the interview of course without badmouthing my employer, especially that those are common problems in startups?

**PS:** I know there are other questions talking about this particular topic, but I just wanted some help for my specific situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best response should be positive and should paint you in a good light, I would use something along the lines of:

> You said your current project is interesting, why are you want to leave that project?

*"While I enjoy the project, I remain unfulfilled in my other needs. I want to grow and develop myself through new challenges, working with your company"*

Answer (score 1):

Avoid taking a figurative dump on your current company. Recruiters really don't like that. Say anything thats formulated positively while still beeing truthful, such as the "Im looking for new challenges" line.

Its tired, yes. But the "Why are you leaving your current company" line isn't there for you to stand out positively. Its there to serve as a red flag of unprofessional behavior if people decide to wail on their current company first chance they get.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, I've had numerous interviews and that has always been my answer. But at some point, I felt that some recruiters didn't believe that for a reason.

Comment: @midihenry even if they don't, thats not the point. At best this question will result in no negative impression against you. The question is there simply to see if you would be unprofessional enough to badmouth your old employer.